# JQuery UI min version 1.10.4 throws Uncaught TypeError even without content

Tags: jquery

I downloaded the newest stabile JQuery UI, along with the theme, however, even when I just have a page with only HTML header and nothing between the  tags, or a nice li'l webform and stuff, I still get this error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined jquery-ui.min.js:103
e.extend.plugin.add jquery-ui.min.js:103
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:873
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.min.js:1086
```

And this error in Opera:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'a.plugins' to object
Error thrown at line 103, column 14 in <anonymous function: add>(t, i, n) in http://localhost/js/jquery-ui.min.js:
    a.plugins[s] = a.plugins[s] || [], a.plugins[s].push([i, n[s]])
called from line 546, column 1 in <anonymous function>(t) in http://localhost/js/jquery-ui.min.js:
    t.widget("ui.draggable", t.ui.mouse,
called from line 545, column 0 in http://localhost/js/jquery-ui.min.js:
    (function (t) {
```

What could cause this and how could this be fixed? Right now the content is at http://cpp.me.pn/

Comment: did you try the latest 1.x version of jQuery instead of 2.x

Comment: also try http://plnkr.co/edit/NdPACHUor5z9srnZqhn9?p=preview - use a cdn version of jQuery

Comment: CDN-ing didn't really help, however switching to 1.x version of jQuery did work.
The error is still there, however, which is curious.

Comment: but the plunker seems to be working - there is no error logged there

Comment: now what is the fix you are going with

Comment: Turns out that issue was with the min version of jquery UI. As soon as I switched to full version (ex. from plunker) everything worked without errors. So in the end I'm gonna go with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48775/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-thara)